# What is the correct use of "even" as an adverb, with the verb "to be"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

http://www.onestopenglish.com/community/your-english/word-grammar/your-english-word-grammar-even/156431.article gives some examples of correct use of "even" as an adverb to indicate that something is surprising or unexpected:-

> "She even forgot my birthday"
>
> "He can’t even spell his own name!"

However, using "even" with "to be" results in some odd-sounding sentences:-

> "[Will you even be there?](http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/3530822107859431131/)"
>
> "[Who even is she?](http://whoismargaretthatcher.tumblr.com/post/47457305489/aliceloweryx)"

And, (famously?)

> "[What even is that thing?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1MGnHrn2BM)"

Adverbs usually come after auxiliary verbs, but in this case it doesn't seem like moving the adverb makes a more pleasing sentence:-

> "What is even that thing?"
>
> "What is that thing even?"

**Is there a correct way those sentences could even be formed, or should "even" not even be used with "to be"?**

As an additional point, these formations seem very common - especially colloquially or in writing on the internet. Is there anywhere I would be able to investigate the frequency of usage and perhaps find some early examples?

EDIT:-

For anyone interested, I found these:-

- http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2943
- http://www.benyagoda.com/post/what-does-what-does-even-mean-even-mean

Suggesting that the use of "even" in this context is new/wrong, rather than specifically the pairing with "to be", e,g:-

> "[What does that even mean?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4077199)"
>
> "[How does that even work?](https://forums.eveonline.com/default.aspx?g=posts&m=1814750)"
>
> "[Is that even a thing?](http://cheezburger.com/5407841792)"

Comment: What is that thing even supposed to be?

Comment: That's a tricky one. I think the appropriateness of "even" has to do with whether there's an implied comparison. E.g., "She not only forgot my email address, she even forgot my birthday!" It can be used with "to be" if there's a comparison implied, e.g., "He's even a tenured professor!" (you thought he'd be just a visiting lecturer). "Will you even be there?" sounds fine to me, implying "I'm afraid you not only won't participate, you won't show up at all."

Comment: "Will you even be there?" sound fine to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OED's entry for the usage OP is concerned with says...

> Intimating that the sentence expresses *an extreme case of a more general proposition implied* (= French même). ***Prefixed*** (in later use often parenthetically postfixed) *to the particular word, phrase, or clause, on which the extreme character of the statement or supposition depends*.

It also goes on to say...

> This use, now the prevailing one in Eng., is foreign to the other Germanic langs. It is rare in purely dialectal speech, and (though a natural development of 8) seems not to have arisen before the 16th c.

(OED's definition 8 refers to a largely obsolete usage where *even = ‘namely’, ‘that is to say’, ‘just’, ‘nothing else but’, ‘to be sure’, ‘forsooth’*).

---

Note that although they're very similar in meaning, there's a slight distinction between...

> 1: She even forgot my birthday
>    2: She forgot even my birthday

In #1, it's implied she *performed other different actions* besides forgetting my birthday (maybe she [ate my last Rolo](http://www.firebox.com/product/739/My-Last-Rolo), for example). In this case, *even* modifies the entire phrase *forgot my birthday*.

But #2 more specifically implies that she ***forgot*** other things (not necessarily even relating to me).

---

There's nothing at all "odd" about OP's *"Will you even be there?"* (it's emphasising that not only might you not *do* something when you're "there" - there's some question as to whether you will be there at all).

OP's *"Who even is she?"* and *"What even is that thing?"* are highly unlikely constructions that would probably be considered unacceptable/substandard by most native speakers. The reason for this is that *even* never really modifies the verb *to be* at all - it modifies *whatever comes **next***, as in...

> "Can't you even be polite?" (If you can't be/act how I want, can you at least be polite?).
>    "I can't even be bothered to reply" (I can't do much at all, specifically not *bother to reply*).

Comment: Good answer. I'd just add that I don't consider _even_ to be an adverb. It is often a pragmatic marker (annoyance) ( in _She **even** forgot my birthday!_) but always has the extreme-indicating sense the OED eloquently describes. It usually 'modifies' a noun group or identifier (Even she forgot my birthday; She forgot even my birthday / **my** birthday) or a clause (She even forgot my birthday) but can 'modify' a verb (He slapped him, he punched him - he even kicked him). However, this isn't a central adverbial function, saying something further about the action itself, but contextualising it.

Comment: @Edwin: Borrowing from Johnson, I suspect that classifying words as *adverbs* is sometimes the last refuge of a desperate grammarian. They should just man up and admit that *even* is in a class of its own (as, in the final analysis, are quite a few other words/usages! :)

Comment: There are a few 'multi-purpose' (or 'multi-positional') 'contextualising modifiers', often grouped together as **limiting modifiers**: only, even, almost, nearly, hardly, merely, scarcely, barely, simply, just, & but (in he was but a youth). But I don't think _even_ fulfils a limiting role.

Comment: I think the "even" in "What even is that thing?" serves no other purpose than as a generic intensifier, much like "the heck", but having said that, it's still quite unusual.

Comment: @BoltClock: I've no doubt anyone who says *"What even is that thing?"* thinks that way. But currently I'm not convinced *any* native speakers would use it. To me, it seems far more suggestive of "non-native speaker error" than a dialectal or slang usage.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but not your examples. I think you have it backwards: I would say "She forgot our anniversary. She forgot Christmas. She even forgot my birthday." There, "even" modifies "forgot." She forgets a, forgets b, and even forgets c. As described, "even" precedes the unusual thing -- her extreme forgetfulness. Conversely: she forgot his, birthday, and her birthday, and even my birthday. The unusual thing is that the birthday she forgot is mine. Even my birthday was forgotten!

Comment: To carry this further: "Alice forgot my birthday. Bob forgot my birthday. Even Carol forgot my birthday!" Would describe a case where the unusual thing is the fact that it was *Carol* who forgot my birthday in the third sentence --Alice and Bob are understandable, but Carol is my best friend, how could *she* forget? The parenthetical version of that last sentence, where the postfix is allowed, would be: "Carol, even, forgot my birthday." "Even" still modifies "Carol."

Answer (score -4):

Use of EVEN...!

By :Santosh Thapa Magar
(resident of Rupandehi, Nepal)

1. She didn't even see me.(In love- She doesn't love me.)
2. It is hot even in winter.(It means there must have been very hot in summer.)
3. Even a child can understand.
   (It means adults must have understood.)

Comment: Those things don't mean what you think they mean.

Comment: What even is this?